# Upload file to IIS from C# client

Tags: c#, iis, file-upload

I have an application running in IIS6/7.
My client is a C# application (no UI) that sends HTTP requests to the server.

What is the best way to implement upload mechanism (without UI controls)?

Thanks,

Comment: That's nice, a minus without a comment. Very constructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create something on the server to receive the file (checks it and authenticate the user) such as an Http Handler. The implementation is easy as Context.Request.SaveAs(...);

The client can:

```
        var r = WebRequest.Create("http://blabla/Update.ashx?fn=a.file");
        var content = File.ReadAllBytes("a.file");
        r.GetRequestStream().Write(content,0,content.Length);
        r.Method = "POST";
        var response = r.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 1):

[WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/36s52zhs.aspx) Method is the easiest way